# CRM Auto Pre-filter doesn't pass a query

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, dynamics-crm-2013

I've created a simple SSRS report using Visual Studio 2012,

I'm using `CRMAF_` prefix to use CRM's auto filtering, and achieve a context-based report.

I'm using two datasets to achieve this; `dsFiltered` for the filtered data, and `dsApprovalSummary` for my report.

This is the query `dsFiltered` uses :

```
declare @sql as nVarchar(max)
set @sql = 'SELECT vrp_investdocumentid
FROM (' + @CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument + ') as CRMAF_vrp_investdocument'
exec(@sql)
```

This is the query `dsApprovalSummary` uses :

```
select doc.vrp_name as 'Yatırım Dosyası', 
        act.vrp_actioncode as 'Aksiyon Kodu',
        cfg.vrp_description as 'Aksiyon Açıklaması',
        act.OwnerIdName as 'Aksiyon Sorumlusu',
        act.ModifiedOn as 'Son Değiştirme Tarihi'
from vrp_action act
inner join vrp_investdocument as doc on act.RegardingObjectId=doc.vrp_investdocumentId
inner join vrp_actionconfig as cfg on act.vrp_actioncode = cfg.vrp_actioncode
where cfg.vrp_reporttask=1 and act.RegardingObjectId = @documentId
order by act.ModifiedOn
```

The parameters are :

> **@CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument** - The parameter CRM should have been populated with a query, defaults to null
>
> **@CRM_vrp_investdocumentId** - Comes from dsFiltered (`CRMAF_vrp_investdocument.vrp_investdocumentid`); allows null.

The report works perfectly on the development server. However, when i deploy the report into the production server, **it does not ask me to select a filter**, or does not have a default filter; tries to run **directly** and then gives an `rsProcessingAborted`. I've checked the logs, and saw it said *`SYNTAX ERROR NEAR )`*-.

This is from the report server logs :

```
processing!ReportServer_0-20!13ec!11/11/2014-13:45:04:: w WARN: Data source 'srcApprovalSummary': Report processing has been aborted. 
processing!ReportServer_0-20!13ec!11/11/2014-13:45:04:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: ,
 Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing.
 ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'dsFiltered'.
 ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Incorrect syntax near ')'
```

**UPDATE :** On the **development** server, we have everything installed *on the same machine*; CRM Frontend, Services, SQL Server, Report Server etc. But on the **production** environment, each one of *these servers are different machines*. Could this be the source of error?

**UPDATE 2 :** Running the profiler gave me that `@CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument` comes in `NULL`. See the query below from the profiler :

```
exec sp_executesql N'declare @sql as nVarchar(max)

set @sql = ''SELECT vrp_investdocumentid

FROM ('' + @CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument + '') as CRMAF_vrp_investdocument''

exec(@sql)',N'@CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument nvarchar(4000)',@CRM_Filteredvrp_investdocument=NULL
```

Comment: This reports works as expected on the development server, does that fields data type really matter?

Comment: sorry ,that is only a column name change not a value check, my mistake.

Comment: Have you tried to run SQL profiler to see what is the query that is actually being executed on sql server? could be parameter is not passed correctly for any reason...

Comment: I'll run a profiler and post the results here, btw, CRM doesn't let me choose or edit the filter when i'm running the report at the production environment, it tries to run the report directly, like a non-fetch based custom report. I'm now updating the question with this information. Thank you.

Comment: I've updated the question, parameter is not being passed at all.

Comment: Why are you using dynamic SQL in your `dsFiltered` query? Why not just `SELECT vrp_investdocumentid FROM Filteredvrp_investdocument as CRMAF_vrp_investdocument`?

Comment: Already tried that, but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Check the order of the datasets in your report (I'm assuming `dsFiltered` is first). Then in your Prod environment - delete the report completely and create a new one using the updated RDL file. I've seen some changes to param behaviors (especially default values) only take effect when new report entries are created in CRM.

Comment: Yeah, dsFiltered is the first one. And i've already tried deleting and creating a new one for my changes, didn't work.

Comment: Check the collation settings of your production database. When it is case sensitive, the query will not run.

Comment: Have you checked that the datasources are correct for both of your datasets? To be sure, rebuild using datasource builder GUI which generates the connection string with a specific syntax which CRM replaces updates when you import the report.

Comment: The datasources work on the dev server, so why would they be incorrect? I've managed to get the report work on the prod server by changing the connection string to `MSCRM Data Connector Connection String`,but it *still* does not ask for a filter, it just gets the first record it can by `select top 1`, and generate a report for it. Any ideas?

Comment: What are the options set for the respective parameter you want the user to be prompted for? Can you post screenshots of the parameter configurations as you see them in the report editor?

Comment: I want the user to select a "vpr_investdocument" record, or run the report based on a selected one (like from the form)

Comment: I understand. So `dsApprovalSummary` should depend on the parameter which the user selects the `vpr_inventdocumentid` (sourced by `dsFiltered`) - it looks like you are calling this `@documentId` (based on the SQL query). As long as the respective `@documentId` parameter in your report is not hidden/internal _and_ doesn't provide a default value, you should see the prompt. As a quick question - if you update (hardcode) the datasources to work against the production database in the in the report editor, does the report Preview (within the report editor) work as you expect?

Comment: Yes, if i hardcode the id, or populate `@documentId` with a select & where clause, it shows the preview as expected.

Comment: I was suggesting to hardcode the _datasource_ to a connection to the Prod CRM database. This would run the report against Prod data. From here we want to see if the report editor preview gives you the behavior you want. If it does, we know the issue is CRM, if it doesn't then the issue the report.

Comment: I'll give it a try asap and get back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65156/discussion-between-seckin-and-jason-faulkner).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out to be a collation problem, i've been trying to use a custom data source with this connection string :

```
Data Source=myprodsqlserver; Initial Catalog=myorganization_MSCRM;
```

I've rewritten it *lowercase*, and replaced the data source with `localhost` the problem is magically gone.

```
data source=localhost; initial catalog=myorganization_MSCRM;
```

Comment: Awesome. Glad you got it working. So was the problem ultimately that the dev and prod SQL installs had different collations?

Comment: Exactly, prod database was `turkish_ci_ai`; which as capital İ's and lower ı's (without the dot). So i'm guessing it couldn't read "Initial Catalog" because of the uppercase "I". Weird, isn't it?

Comment: @JasonFaulkner, this bounty is expiring, you can post an answer if you want, i can upvote and accept your answer, so you can get the bounty, as a thank you gift for your help

Comment: Thanks for the offer - I'll post my last comment (the one which led to finding the solution) as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

In the report editor, try rebuilding the datasource used by each of your datasets using the connection string builder (don't type it manually). Build them so they point to your Prod CRM database and then test the report completely in the report editor. This will determine if the problem is lies with the report or CRM.